# How can I identify the number of occurrences of multiple custom emotions, grouped by line, team, and personal ID?

Tags: r, text, count, nlp

I have a data frame like the following (but much larger and with repeated observations across time):

```
df <- data.frame(
participant_ID = 1:4, 
TeamID = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
Text1 = c(
    "I shouted angrily, but then felt happy. Now I am very happy.",
    "He is always calm and never gets angry",
    "She laughed, making everyone happy",
    "I'm feeling sad today"
  ), 
)
```

I also have the following custom dictionary with examples of what I am looking for within the text as an example of each emotion. Using simple emotions as an example:

```
emotions <- c(
  anger = c("angry", "shouted"),
  happiness = c("happy", "laughed"),
  sadness = c("sad")
)
```

My goal is to count the number of each emotion group, separated by ID, and store it in a new data frame. Ideally, the output looks something like:

```
  ID TeamID anger happiness sadness 
1  1      A     1         2       0
2  2      A     1         0       0
3  3      B     0         2       0
4  4      B     0         0       1
```

I tried creating an empty data frame to store the emotion counts with participant IDs:

```
emotion_count_df <- data.frame(ID = integer(0), Emotion = character(0), Count = integer(0))
```

and wrote a function to count how many times each emotion occurred in the text (and converting to lowercase):

```
count_emotions <- function(text, emotions) {
  text <- tolower(text)
  counts <- sapply(emotions, function(emotion) sum(grepl(paste(emotion, collapse = "|"), text)))
  return(counts)
}
```

Then I tried to loop through the df, count emotions for each emotion and row, and store my results in the new data frame:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  counts <- count_emotions(df$Text[i], emotions)
  for (j in 1:length(emotions)) {
    emotion_count_df <- rbind(emotion_count_df, data.frame(ID = df$ID[i], Emotion = names(emotions)[j], Count = counts[j]))
  }
}
```

But I received the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(ID = df$ID[i], Emotion = names(emotions)[j],  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: first `emotions` should be a `list(...` not `c(....` since you can have multiple key words for each. second you are getting the error because your variable is called `participant_ID` in `df`, not `ID`, so it should be `ID = df$participant_ID[i]`. and instead of the nested loop you can do something like `cbind(df, t(sapply(df$Text1, count_emotions, emotions, USE.NAMES = FALSE)))`

Comment: If you are analyzing free text, then you will need to detect and distinguish “not happy” as being the opposite sentiment compared to “happy”.

Comment: @rawr thanks for the list recommendation, I got it to work